# Differences between cubic 2D interpolation methods in scipy and pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, scipy, interpolation

Both SciPy and PyTorch have multiple ways of interpolating 2D images. However, for cubic interpolation they don't appear to be doing the same thing. Why are they so different?

So far I've found that the following seem to be doing the same thing at `order=1`/`mode=linear`/`mode=bilinear` (up to floating point errors):

- `scipy.interpolate.interpn`
- `scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates`
- `torch.nn.functional.interpolate` with `align_corners=True`
- `torch.nn.functional.grid_sample` with `align_corners=True`

However, at order 3 all of them are different from each other.

As there are so many different functions I will accept partial answers that explain differences between some of them.

Here's an (attempted) minimal example (still quite long). The example is simply using the interpolation methods to upsample a random image.

```py
# Computations
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing
import torch
from scipy.interpolate import interpn
from scipy.ndimage import map_coordinates
from torch.nn.functional import interpolate, grid_sample

# Visualizations
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm


def get_interpolated_values(
    original_size: tuple[int, int],
    sample_size: tuple[int, int],
    order: int,
) -> list[np.typing.NDArray], list[str]:
    '''Returns list of interpolated images with labels for which interpolation
    method was used.'''

    # Initialize source values for interpolation
    values = np.random.rand(*original_size)
    order2str = [
        'nearest',
        'linear',
        None,
        'cubic',
    ]

    # Initialize data collection
    labels = []
    interpolated_values = []

    # Scipy interpn
    labels.append('scipy.interpn')
    interpolated_values.append(
        interpn(
            points=(
                np.mgrid[0 : original_size[0]],
                np.mgrid[0 : original_size[1]],
            ),
            values=values,
            xi=np.stack(np.mgrid[
                0 : original_size[0] - 1 : sample_size[0] * 1j,
                0 : original_size[1] - 1 : sample_size[1] * 1j,
            ], axis=-1),
            method=order2str[order],
            bounds_error=True,
        )
    )

    # Scipy map_coordinates
    labels.append('scipy.map_coordinates')
    interpolated_values.append(
        map_coordinates(
            input=values,
            coordinates=np.mgrid[
                0 : original_size[0] - 1 : sample_size[0] * 1j,
                0 : original_size[1] - 1 : sample_size[1] * 1j,
            ],
            order=order,
            mode='constant',
        )
    )

    # Torch interpolate with align_corners
    value_tensor = torch.from_numpy(values)[None, None, ...]
    labels.append('torch.interpolate')
    interpolated_values.append(
        interpolate(
            input=value_tensor,
            size=sample_size,
            align_corners=True,
            mode="bi" + order2str[order],
        ).squeeze().numpy()
    )

    # Torch grid sample with corners
    labels.append('torch.grid_sample')
    interpolated_values.append(
        grid_sample(
            input=value_tensor,
            grid=torch.from_numpy(
                np.mgrid[
                    -1 : 1 : sample_size[0] * 1j,
                    -1 : 1 : sample_size[1] * 1j,
                ],
            ).moveaxis(0, -1).unsqueeze(0).flip(-1),
            padding_mode='zeros',
            mode="bi" + order2str[order],
            align_corners=True,
        ).squeeze().numpy()
    )

    return interpolated_values, labels


def visualize(interpolated_values, labels):

    # Visualize each interpolated result
    fig, ax_row = plt.subplots(1, len(interpolated_values))
    for i_ax, ax in enumerate(ax_row):
        ax.set_title(labels[i_ax])
        im = ax.imshow(interpolated_values[i_ax], vmin=0, vmax=1)
    plt.colorbar(im)

    # Visualise differences between methods
    fig, ax_grid = plt.subplots(
        len(interpolated_values),
        len(interpolated_values),
    )
    fig.suptitle('Interpolation differences')

    for i_ax, ax_row in enumerate(ax_grid):
        for j_ax, ax in enumerate(ax_row):
            if i_ax == j_ax:
                # Add label in diagonal
                ax.text(
                    *((n - 1) / 2 for n in interpolated_values[i_ax].shape),
                    s=labels[i_ax],
                    ha='center',
                    va='center',
                )

            # Plot difference matrix with colorbar
            diff = interpolated_values[i_ax] - interpolated_values[j_ax]
            im = ax.imshow(np.abs(diff))
            plt.colorbar(im)


def main():
    interpolated_values, labels = get_interpolated_values(
        original_size = (4, 4),
        sample_size = (5, 5),
        order = 3,
    )
    visualize(interpolated_values, labels)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here's the visualized absolute differences at order 3:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

(Partial answer) the difference between interpn (which is a convenience wrapper over RegularGridInterpolator) and ndimage.map_coordinates is that the latter assumes equidistant integer valued grid, while the former allows more general grid spacings (still regular, but can vary between dimensions). Here's one example from the scipy docs:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate/ND_regular_grid.html

Comment: I was rather asking about the difference in output when both methods can be used. As in the example I gave. But the link you gave says this towards the end: "Note that the example above uses the map_coordinates boundary conditions. Thus, results of the cubic and quintic interpolations may differ from those of the RegularGridInterpolator." So if there are different boundary conditions used when fitting the splines, that could explain the differences.

Comment: There is more on boundary conditions here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/ndimage.html#interpolation-boundary-handling

Comment: Yes, BCs definitely play a role! RGI's splines use not-a-knot, which is often not very appropriate for image processing.

Comment: I'd accept that as an answer. :)